# d3 bar chart y axis ticks and grid lines above max value

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, charts

In my d3 bar chart, I should have Y-axis dynamic ticks and grid lines for integer values (no ticks and grid lines for decimal values). Also there should be tick and grid line at the top of tallest bar.

Here in my sample chart, I am passing the max value to the y axis domain function, how can I make sure to have one more line and tick if the max value doesn't reach the next range.

[**Fiddle One**](https://jsfiddle.net/betasquirrel/pnyn7vzj/1/) Here the second bar has total value of 53, so I am expecting one more tick and line at 55.

[**Fiddle Two**](https://jsfiddle.net/betasquirrel/0k4qa25f/1/) For the same chart, if the data goes below 10, it comes with lines at decimal points like 2.5, 3.5, etc. How to exclude these lines.

Here the ticks are calculated based on value.

```
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "14" },
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2009", redDelicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2010", redDelicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2011", redDelicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" },
  { year: "2012", redDelicious: "04", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "8", pears: "1" },
  { year: "2013", redDelicious: "06", mcintosh: "11", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2014", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "13", oranges: "9", pears: "5" },
  { year: "2015", redDelicious: "16", mcintosh: "19", oranges: "6", pears: "9" },
  { year: "2016", redDelicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" },
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat(d3.format("d"));

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Anjou pears";
      case 1: return "Naval oranges";
      case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Question 1**

You are probably going to have to use [tickValues](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickValues) to pass your own custom ticks.  If you are generally happy with how `d3` does it, you can just add an extra check to extend the array:

```
var ticks = y.ticks(),
  lastTick = ticks[ticks.length-1],
  newLastTick = lastTick + (ticks[1] - ticks[0]);
if (lastTick<y.domain()[1]){
  ticks.push(newLastTick);
}
y.domain([y.domain()[0], newLastTick]); //<-- adjust domain for further value

// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } )
  .tickValues(ticks);
```

---

Running code:

```js
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

var margin = {top: 15, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "14" },
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2009", redDelicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2010", redDelicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2011", redDelicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" },
  { year: "2012", redDelicious: "04", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "8", pears: "1" },
  { year: "2013", redDelicious: "06", mcintosh: "11", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2014", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "13", oranges: "9", pears: "5" },
  { year: "2015", redDelicious: "16", mcintosh: "19", oranges: "6", pears: "9" },
  { year: "2016", redDelicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" },
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];

var ticks = y.ticks(),
    lastTick = ticks[ticks.length-1],
    newLastTick = lastTick + (ticks[1] - ticks[0]);
if (lastTick<y.domain()[1]){
  ticks.push(newLastTick);
}
y.domain([y.domain()[0], newLastTick]);

// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } )
  .tickValues(ticks);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });
 
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});
 
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Anjou pears";
      case 1: return "Naval oranges";
      case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");
    
tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
  }
 
  path.domain {
    stroke: none;
  }
 
  .y .tick line {
    stroke: #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**Question 2**

Again, you can let `d3` come up with the ticks and then filter out the ones you don't want:

```
var ticks = y.ticks().filter(function(d){
  return parseInt(d) === d; // is it a integer?
})

// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
.tickValues(ticks);
```

Running code:

```js
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "1", mcintosh: "3" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "2", mcintosh: "1"},
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "0", mcintosh: "2"}
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];

var ticks = y.ticks().filter(function(d){
 return parseInt(d) === d;
})

// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickValues(ticks);
  
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });
 
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});
 
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Anjou pears";
      case 1: return "Naval oranges";
      case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");
    
tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
  svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
  }
 
  path.domain {
    stroke: none;
  }
 
  .y .tick line {
    stroke: #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here I can see only one issue, sometimes the extra top y axis tick cuts inside the SVG container as the SVG boundary ends. Any work around for this? My container height and width is accessed using the container element, not hard coded.

Comment: @devo, good question.  You should adjust the `y.domain` after padding the ticks further out.  See updated answer above to question 1.